# How to play a stream video in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, video-streaming, windows-phone-8.1

I have a problem with opening the default media player, to play a video (a stream URI from youtube) in Windows Phone 8.1.

When I wrote to Windows Phone 8.0, I used

```
MediaPlayerLauncher mediaPlayerLauncher = new MediaPlayerLauncher();

//...

mediaPlayerLauncher.Show();

and now I'm using (Windows Phone 8.1):

    bool success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(_videoUrl, options);
```

which opens IE file download with a open/save dialog.

If I click on open it's open the Windows Media Player and play the video as I wanted

How can I skip the save file dialog and automatically open the Windows Media Player with my Youtube stream URI?

Comment: Is it to stream or to play the video?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet) in order to stream the channel you want?

The sample from the [msdn](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Youtube-Sample-Get-Youtube-e9a3e0be) might help you.